# Logging into another another person's account

Tags: credentials

There were instances in the past where I logged in with my own credentials, but it showed me as a different user after logging in.

How does this usually happen?

Comment: Logged into _what_? Facebook?

Comment: It happened in a forum bbs, which I could not recall. I'm reading on materials on access controls and session management, so this kind of crossed my mind. Could that be an error in the session management / database?

Comment: The main question to clarify what happened would be: Was that other user using the same computer before you?

Comment: Nope, that user was definitely not someone I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the code that's used to create this login form. You have to give us more information than this. Like, where, what code is being used, how did you log in and a code snippet of the backend would be very good, and so on.

But, here is some things that I felt in my mind that could be the cause:

- The session is invalid in that way that you have another session id
  which is accidentally a session that another user owns. (If you are
  using a session)
- Database is queried wrong - It selects the wrong username or id for
  some reason. Not very likely but it's possible.
- A cookie is storing the login credentials and you accidentally logged in with  that cookie.

  This could be the reason too,
  Jak Gib mentioned in the comments below:

  > This can sometimes occur when web server caching is misconfigured. There was a large incident recently with Steam. Users who logged in where given the cached pages for other users which contained personal details, making it appear they had logged in as somebody else.

Well, that is all I can come up with as your question is not giving me very much information.

You could comment on my answer with more information and I can possible help you more :)

Comment: Hi Arnar, that question just came up as a general question as it's something I thought about as I'm just reading up on very basic materials relating to information security. I think your answer pretty much cleared my doubt. I'll look deeper into these areas. Thank you.

Comment: This can sometimes occur when web server caching is misconfigured.
There was a large incident recently with Steam. Users who logged in where given the cached pages for other users which contained personal details, making it appear they had logged in as somebody else.
See the below for more information on this:
http://www.pcworld.com/article/3018481/software/psa-steam-having-serious-issues-with-account-security-at-the-moment.html

Comment: Wow, things like that happen to these large vendors too?